# Grep exact number of digits and some other characters

Tags: text-processing, grep, regular-expression

I'd like to parse a file containing 5 digit numbers separated by comma or dash, lines like :
12345,23456,34567-45678,12345-23456,34567

My goal is to find lines which have incorrect formatting eg. lines which contain numbers which are not composed of 5 digits being separated by other characters than comma or dash.

I tried to egrep the file with :

`cat file.txt | egrep  -v [-,]*[0-9]{5}[,-]*`

- but if I have a 6 digit number, it is matched, and the line is not displayed
- and if I have a 4 digit number, it is not matched but other numbers from 
  that same line are matched and the line is not displayed

To specify the lines content :

- a number must be of 5 digits
- ranges are defined with dash, like 12345-12389
- a line can contain anything from a single number to several numbers and ranges in any order

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: You might want to show some correct lines, and incorrect lines to give people more to go on (show as much variation as possible).

Comment: added some more details. maybe grep+regex is not the best solution to parse his....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
grep -vxE '([0-9]{5}[,-])*[0-9]{5}'
```

Would report the incorrect lines.

Or if you also want to forbid `12345-12345-12345`:

```
num='[0-9]{5}'
num_or_range="$num(-$num)?"
grep -vxE "($num_or_range,)*$num_or_range"
```

Answer (score 5):

For a good `grep` solution, see [Stéphane's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/276669/22222). As an alternative, here's a Perl one:

```
perl -ne 'print if grep{$_!~/^\d{5}$/} split(/[,-]/); ' file
```

That will split each input line on `,` or `-` and then will look for members of the split array that don't consist of exactly 5 numbers. If any are found, the line is printed.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `cat`. Does this do what you want:

```
 $ grep -v -E '^([0-9]{5}(,|-))+' <FILE>
```

For example, if `FILE` had the following contents:

```
12345,23456,34567-45678,12345-23456,34567
1,2
12345*23456,34567-45678,12345-23456,34567
123456
1234*23456,34567-45678,12345-23456,34567
```

result would be:

```
$ grep -v -E '^([0-9]{5}(,|-))+' 5d
1,2
12345*23456,34567-45678,12345-23456,34567
123456
1234-23456,34567-45678,12345-23456,34567
```

Comment: This will fail if a line contains only 5 numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your effort ! As @terdon mentioned this fails in some cases, but it's very close.

Comment: @mazs: ok, I thought you always expected `-` or `,` to be there between numbers.